# CD_Dynamic Configuration for JNDI

Tags: 2013, dd4t-java

We would like use JNDI names for  configurations in `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` files for DD4T Java project, for example Publication ID or port number.  We have defined this in the `dispachter-servlet.xml` file.

```
<property name="properties">
    <bean class="java.util.Properties">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="dwa.tridion.cdDynamic.pubIdNL">
                    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="cell/persistent/dwa/tridion/cdDynamic/pubIdNL" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean> 
</property>
```

Does SDL support JNDI names in the `cd_*_conf.xml` file? If so, is there any example we can be referred to?

Comment: Please add your Tridion version. I believe 8.5 can use variables for most configuration values, not sure of previous versions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Nuno! we are using Tridion 2013 for now :-(.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware of you can use JNDI names for data sources in the Content Delivery configuration files.

If you [search](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Tridion+full+documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Djndi&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1505801942046&currentQuery=jndi&currentScope=&eventType=lcSearch.runSearch1505801942046) the 2013 documentation for `jndi` you will see the locations of where it is mentioned, for example in `cd_storage_conf.xml`:

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-27C4B58F-A922-4CFD-8F9A-7E650CF31692

> A named JNDI property for the JMS Connector.

and

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-C822C094-680C-4C75-9F1E-726833BFE1C2

> JNDIName - Specifies the JNDI name of a Datasource to use. When used, No other attributes or a DataSource may be specified.